# Edit token template

Tags: tokens

I am using "Send mail with Variable" module and my variable contains the token [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items], which returns me `<table style="width: 50%;border: 1px solid #ddd;">`. I need other CSS styles.
 Because it is a body of a e-mail, I can use only inline styles. Where I can find a template of this token?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any template used to populate that token. The function that is called to generate the content of that token is `commerce_email_order_items()`, which then calls `theme_commerce_email_order_items()`.

To alter the content of the token, you have two options:

- Override the theme function. It's easier, but it could change the output also in other contexts.
- Implement [`hook_tokens_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7) to alter the output of that token. It's not as easier as the previous solution, but it's more specific, and you are sure you are not going to alter the output of `theme('commerce_email_order_items')` done from other modules and in other circumstances.

This is the involved code used by the module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function commerce_email_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $url_options = array('absolute' => TRUE);

  if (isset($options['language'])) {
    $url_options['language'] = $options['language'];
    $language_code = $options['language']->language;
  }
  else {
    $language_code = NULL;
  }

  $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);

  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'commerce-order' && !empty($data['commerce-order'])) {
    $order = $data['commerce-order'];

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'commerce-email-order-items':
          $order_items = commerce_email_order_items($order);
          $replacements[$original] = $order_items;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}

/**
 * Returns a rendered email of the commerce order
 * or an array of the table details
 *
 * @param $order
 *   The commerce order object
 *   
 * @param $theme
 * (optional) Defaults to TRUE
 *   Flag to return the contents of the order
 *   as a themed html table or an array suitable for theme('table' ...)
 *   
 * @return
 *   String containing the rendered order table
 *   or an array suitable for theme('table' ...)
 */
function commerce_email_order_items($order, $theme = TRUE) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

  if ($theme) {
    return theme('commerce_email_order_items', array('commerce_order_wrapper' => $wrapper));
  }
  else {
    return commerce_email_prepare_table($wrapper);
  }
}

/**
 * Theme function for the commerce order.
 */
function theme_commerce_email_order_items($variables) {
  $table = commerce_email_prepare_table($variables['commerce_order_wrapper']);
  return theme('table', $table);
}

/**
 * Returns a table header and rows for theming.
 *
 * @param $wrapper
 *   A metadata-wrapped commerce_order entity
 *
 * @return array
 *   Array suitable for use by theme('table' ...)
 */
function commerce_email_prepare_table($wrapper) {
  $currency_code = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->currency_code->value();
  $amount = number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($wrapper->commerce_order_total->amount->value(), $currency_code), 2);

  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('Product'), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
    array('data' => t('Qty'), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
    array('data' => t('Price (@currency_code)', array('@currency_code' => $currency_code)), 'style' => array('text-align: left;'))
  );

  $rows = array();
  foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {

    switch ($line_item_wrapper->type->value()) {
      case 'product':
        // Special treatment for a product, since we want to get the title from
        // from the product entity instead of the line item.
        $title = htmlentities($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->title->value(), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $title .= commerce_email_order_item_attributes($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->product_id->value());

        $rows[] = array(
          'data' => array(
            array('data' => $title, 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
            array('data' => $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value(), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
            array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value(), $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
          )
        );
        break;
      default:
        // Use this for any other line item.
        $rows[] = array(
          'data' => array(
            array('data' => htmlentities($line_item_wrapper->line_item_label->value(), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
            array('data' => 1, 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
            array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value(), $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('text-align: left;')),
          )
        );
        break;
    }
  }

  $data = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->data->value();
  if (!empty($data['components'])) {

    foreach ($data['components'] as $key => &$component) {

      if ($data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'base_price') {
        $rows[] = array(
          'data' => array(
            ' ',
            array('data' => t('Subtotal:'), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
            array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'], $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: left;')),
          )
        );
      }
      elseif (preg_match('/^tax\|/', $data['components'][$key]['name'])) {
        $rows[] = array(
          'data' => array(
            ' ',
            array('data' => $data['components'][$key]['price']['data']['tax_rate']['display_title'] . ':', 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
            array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'], $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: left;')),
          )
        ); 
      }
    }
  }

  $rows[] = array(
    'data' => array(
      ' ',
      array('data' => t('Total:'), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
      array('data' => $amount, 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: left;')),
    )
  );

  return array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' => array('style' => array('width: 50%; border: 1px solid #ddd;')));
}
```